# register php page changed to blank page when click the button

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am the new php learner, I am trying build a register and login webpages and connect them to the mysql databases.

I am following a video tutorial, however, when I click the "register" button on register webpage, the register page changed to blank page, I read the similar questions online, and then checked the codes, but the webpage still showed blank page.

I have no idea how to fix it. I used the Atom, there is no error showed and I checked the connection with databases, the password and username of database are correct.

can anyone help me, thank you so much !!!

this is the tutorial link: https://codewithawa.com/posts/complete-user-registration-system-using-php-and-mysql-database

register.php

```
<?php include('server.php') ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>Register</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "register.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "logo_frame">
        <p id ="image_logo"><img src="walogo.png" width = "400" height="400"></p>
</<div>
<div id = "register_frame">
        <form method = "post" action = "register.php">
            <?php include ('errors.php');
            ?>
            <p><label class="label_input">Username : </label><input type = "text" name="username" class = "text_field"/></p>
            <p><label class = "label_input">Password : </label><input type = "text" name ="password" class = "text_field"/></p>
            <p><label class = "label_input">Confirm Password : </label><input type = "text" name ="password2" class = "text_field"/></p>
            <p><input type = "submit" name ="r_btn" value = "register :)"></p>
            <p>Already a member? <a href="login.php">Login</a>
            </p>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

server.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$username = "";
$errors = array();

// test the database connection

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','digital_wallet');

//if registe is clicked
if (isset($_POST['r_btn'])) {
  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);
  $password2= mysql_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password2']);
  // ensure no empty
  if(empty($username)){
    array_push($errors, "username is required");
  }
  if(empty($password)){
    array_push($errors, "password is required");
  }
  if($password != $password2){
    array_push($errors,"the two passwords do not match");
  }

// if there are no errors, save user to db
  if(count($errors) == 0){
    $password = md5($password); // security
    $sql ="INSERT INTO register(username, password,password2) VALUES('$username','$password','$password2')";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
    header('location: wallet.php');
  }
}
?>
```

errors.php

```
<?php if (count($errors) > 0) : ?>
  <div class="error">
    <?php foreach ($errors as $error) : ?>
      <p><?php echo $error ?></p>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </div>
<?php  endif ?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You might be open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I really hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library to get the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

`header('location: wallet.php');`
does this wallet.php file exists?
this command redirects user to wallet.php

Comment: yes, it exists.  the website should go to the wallet.php after complete the registration. but now register page only changed to the blank page when clicked the register button .

Comment: in `if(count($errors) == 0){` make an `else` with `header('location: errors.php');` maybe it fails, also make sure you have an `<input name="r_btn" .../>` you have a lot of if's but not else, so i guess it's default else is blank page @lily